# How can I use Rails 5.2 credentials in capistrano's deploy.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, capistrano3, rollbar

I've just updated my Rails app to 5.2, and configured it to use the new `config/credentials.yml.enc` file.

When I try to deploy, I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails
/Users/me/Documents/project/config/deploy.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

That's pointing to this line in my `config/deploy.rb` file:

```
set :rollbar_token, Rails.application.credentials[:rollbar_token]
```

So it appears that while capistrano is running, it doesn't have access to `Rails.application.credentials`.

How are you all handling this? I've got some ideas...

- Set this one variable as an `ENV` variable

  - I don't love how this separates/customizes this one setting
- Somehow make it so capistrano has access to `Rails.application.credentials`

  - I don't know if this is a good idea or if there are other things I need to be aware of if I go this route
- Remove deploy tracking in rollbar

  - ‍♂️

Answer (score 9):

## Put the following line(s) on top of your `config/deploy.rb`

```
# config/deploy.rb
require File.expand_path("./environment", __dir__)
```

This include make constants like **`Rails.application`** accessible in files like **`config/deploy/production.rb`**. Now things like the following are possible:

```
# config/deploy/staging.rb
server "production.lan", user: "production", roles: %w{app db web}
set :stage, :production
set :branch, "development"
set :pg_password, Rails.application.credentials[:staging][:postgres][:password]
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
set :rollbar_token, YAML.load(`rails credentials:show`)['rollbar_token']
```

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Upload `master.key` the file on the server (user read-only) like so:

```
namespace :setup do
  desc "setup: copy config/master.key to shared/config"
  task :copy_linked_master_key do
    on roles(fetch(:setup_roles)) do
      sudo :mkdir, "-pv", shared_path
      upload! "config/master.key", "#{shared_path}/config/master.key"
      sudo :chmod, "600", "#{shared_path}/config/master.key"
    end
  end
  before "deploy:symlink:linked_files", "setup:copy_linked_master_key"
end
```

Put it in your `lib/capistrano/tasks/setup.rake`

## 2. Ensure file is linked

In `deploy.rb`:

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push("config/master.key")
```

### 3. Ensure Capfile loads the task:

Make sure your `Capfile` has the line

```
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem to the one you've answered above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749047/rails-moving-master-key-to-production-server).  Presumably a very similar approach to what you've outlined here would work if deploying code using `mina`?  I wonder if I need to change `before "deploy:symlink:linked_files", "setup:copy_linked_master_key"` in part 1, and potentially adjust the equivalent of the `capfile`?

Answer (score 3):

It seemed to me non-ideal to load the whole of Rails here, or to have to read command line output, so here's an alternative solution:

```
require "active_support/encrypted_configuration"
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/keys"

module CredentialLoader
  def read_credentials(environment:)
    YAML.load(
      ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration.new(
        config_path: "config/credentials/#{environment}.yml.enc",
        key_path: "config/credentials/#{environment}.key",
        env_key: environment.to_s,
        raise_if_missing_key: true
      ).read
    )   
  end 
end
```

Then you can do this in your `deploy.rb`:

```
include CredentialLoader
set :rollbar_token, read_credentials(environment: fetch(:stage))["rollbar_access_token"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me without the need to load Rails, which was causing me a capistrano translation error.

Answer (score 2):

```
require File.expand_path("./environment", __dir__)
puts App::Application.credentials.rollbar_token
```

Comment: Put `require File.expand_path("./environment", __dir__)` in Your `config/deploy.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solve this is to declare a `$ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable on the server. I place it at the top of `~deployer/.bashrc` like this:

```
export ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN=...
```

Then I integrate with Capistrano by defining this task:

```
task :set_rollbar_token do
  on release_roles(:all).first do
    set :rollbar_token, capture("echo $ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN").chomp
  end
end

before "rollbar:deploy", "set_rollbar_token"
```