# Rails: Moving `master.key` to production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deploy an updated version of a rails app to a droplet on DigitalOcean using `mina`

When I run `mina deploy` I get the error `Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /home/my_rails_project/app/tmp/build-153920174210305/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']`.

I was expecting this error as I haven't yet worked out how to add the details to the server.

A number of articles suggest there are two means of doing [this](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336):

> *Option 1: Place the `config/master.key` file in the server. You’ll normally want to symlink this file to a shared folder in the server
>   filesystem. Again, do not version your `config/master.key` file.*
>
> *Option 2: create a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY ENV` variable. Rails will detect it and use it as your master key, e.g. in heroku: `heroku config:set
>   RAILS_MASTER_KEY= < your-master-key-here >`.*

I have tried option 1 using FileZilla, however, I am unable to access the folder which is where the article suggests the file should be stored `/home/deploy/my-rails-project/shared/config/master.key` -> `Error:          Directory /home/my-rails-project/app/shared/config: permission denied`.  I am also unable to see the `master.key` file on my local computer through FileZilla.  Similarly, if I use the console on Digital Ocean I get the `permission denied` error

**Please could you advise me how to move `master.key` to the production server**

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: did you try option 2? It's add this line `export RAILS_MASTER_KEY="xxx"` on `.bashrc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up working out how to do option 2, as suggested by @edudepetris.  This involved adding the line `RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<my_master.key>` to the top of my `.bashrc` - this was done by typing `nano .bashrc` when logged into the server

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `capistrano-linked-files` Gem (https://github.com/runar/capistrano-linked-files).
This gem provides Capistrano 3.1 reciepes to upload your linked files and directories. Linked files and directories are placed in the `shared` directory on your remote servers and kept between deployments.

Add the gem to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'capistrano-linked-files'
```

Then add the Gem to your `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/linked_files'
```

Now add the master.key to your in deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_files, 'config/master.key'
```

Now you can upload the master key via:

```
$ bundle exec cap <STAGE> linked_files:upload
```

All these details are from the README.md from https://github.com/runar/capistrano-linked-files. Have a look!

### Alternative solution

The `capistrano/rails` Gem (https://github.com/capistrano/rails) has a section about this topic, too.